# slave VM removed from list of slaves and still being accessed by Yarn/Tez

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, master-slave

So I removed the vm4 from the list of slave VMs and when I run the following command it doesn't access it

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

result is:

```
ubuntu@anmol-vm1-new:~$ hdfs dfsadmin -report
15/12/14 06:56:12 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Configured Capacity: 1268169326592 (1.15 TB)
Present Capacity: 1199270457337 (1.09 TB)
DFS Remaining: 1199213064192 (1.09 TB)
DFS Used: 57393145 (54.73 MB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
Under replicated blocks: 27
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 3 (3 total, 0 dead)

Live datanodes:
Name: 10.0.1.191:50010 (anmol-vm2-new)
Hostname: anmol-vm2-new
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 422723108864 (393.69 GB)
DFS Used: 19005440 (18.13 MB)
Non DFS Used: 21501829120 (20.03 GB)
DFS Remaining: 401202274304 (373.65 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 94.91%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Last contact: Mon Dec 14 06:56:12 UTC 2015


Name: 10.0.1.190:50010 (anmol-vm1-new)
Hostname: anmol-vm1-new
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 422723108864 (393.69 GB)
DFS Used: 19369984 (18.47 MB)
Non DFS Used: 25831350272 (24.06 GB)
DFS Remaining: 396872388608 (369.62 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 93.88%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Last contact: Mon Dec 14 06:56:13 UTC 2015


Name: 10.0.1.192:50010 (anmol-vm3-new)
Hostname: anmol-vm3-new
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 422723108864 (393.69 GB)
DFS Used: 19017721 (18.14 MB)
Non DFS Used: 21565689863 (20.08 GB)
DFS Remaining: 401138401280 (373.59 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 94.89%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Last contact: Mon Dec 14 06:56:11 UTC 2015
```

however at some point Yarn tries to access it. Here's the log I received:

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_1450050523156_0009
```

http://pastebin.com/UVHnkRRp

```
Service org.apache.tez.dag.app.rm.TaskScheduler failed in state STARTED; cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: anmol-vm4-new
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:377)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.BaseNMTokenSecretManager.newInstance(BaseNMTokenSecretManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.BaseNMTokenSecretManager.createNMToken(BaseNMTokenSecretManager.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM.createAndGetOptimisticNMToken(NMTokenSecretManagerInRM.java:325)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService.registerApplicationMaster(ApplicationMasterService.java:297)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.registerApplicationMaster(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationMasterProtocol$ApplicationMasterProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationMasterProtocol.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2014)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2010)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1561)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2008)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: anmol-vm4-new
        ... 15 more
```

Any idea why is it trying to access VM4 which is not in slaves list and how that could be fixed?

UPDATE:
I did the following but still I receive an error because it tries to access `vm4`:

1)add the files `exclude` and `mapred.exclude` in `conf` directory of yarnpp including the private IP address of vm4.

2)add this in `mapred-site.xml`:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.hosts.exclude</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/yarnpp/conf/mapred.exclude</value>
    <description>Names a file that contains the list of hosts that
      should be excluded by the jobtracker.  If the value is empty, no
      hosts are excluded.</description>
  </property>
```

3)add this to `hdfs-site.xml`:

```
<property>
 <name>dfs.hosts.exclude</name>
 <value>/home/hadoop/yarnpp/conf/exclude</value>
 <final>true</final>
</property>
```

3.5) added this to `yarn-site.xml`:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.nodes.exclude-path</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/yarnpp/conf/exclude</value>
    <description>Path to file with nodes to exclude.</description>
  </property>
```

4)run cp_host.sh to copy the conf directory to all the slaves!

5)run reboot_everything script (which does `stop-all.sh`, formatting and `start-all.sh`)

6) `hadoop dfsadmin -refreshNodes`

7) run this command in master VM:

```
 yarn rmadmin -refreshNodes
```

And here's the new log: http://pastebin.com/cKPY9gmB

Also even though vm4 is not in the list of VMs it still shows up here:
[image]

And now with all these updates when I am running the `gridmix-generate.sh` job I get this error:

```
15/12/14 10:14:53 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: anmol-vm3-new/10.0.1.192:50833. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

Comment: How did you remove it from the slave node list?

Comment: Have you restarted resource manager after removing the ip from the slaves file?

Comment: @ManjunathBallur I just have a slaves file in conf directory plus I removed it from /etc/hosts

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju yeah I have done stop-all, all formatting and removing the stuff from hdfs and then a start-all with the new setup in /etc/hosts and slaves file

Comment: @MonaJalal, can you run stop-all.sh and run `ps -ef|grep -i manager` on all the nodes to make sure all the services are actually stopped?

Comment: @MonaJalal, also please confirm if the issue is related to only Tez or is it happening to map reduce jobs as well?

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju http://pastebin.com/7mEYpzfy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97828/discussion-between-durga-viswanath-gadiraju-and-mona-jalal).

Comment: I see 1 weird thing. Your Active Nodes is shown as 4 and Decommissioned Nodes as 1. It should be 3 and 1 right? So, I suspect, though you Decommissioned it, the Node Manager is still running on vm4.

Comment: @ManjunathBallur yes that is my question. Do you have any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

After speaking to Mona on chat, issue is fixed now.

When one run stop-all.sh command some times all the processes might not be stopped. It is good practice to run `ps -ef` command to make sure all the processes are stopped on all the nodes. Monal have ran the command stop-all.sh and ran the command `ps -ef|grep -i datanode` and the command is still showing the results.

Then in the chat, I have asked her to reboot all the VMs which will clean up dangling processes. Hard reboot have resolved the issue.

Comment: Network provider performed the hard reboot. Simply doing the stop-all and start-all didn't solve the issue